# Different Results from Grouping query

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I ran following query in MS Access 2007 and get expected results

```
SELECT Col1
FROM tblA
GROUP BY Col1
HAVING ((Count(Col1))>1);
```

But after adding additional column in the same table to the grouping as below. It `gives 0 records`

```
SELECT Col1, Col2
FROM tblA
GROUP BY Col1, Col2
HAVING ((Count(Col1))>1);


Col1        Col2
19570304    180243268
19570304    180243269
19570304    180243270
26984406    422233864
26984951    796883002
26985060    594201758
19700070    150814697
19700070    430871349
19700070    670755019
19700070    883583086
19700070    963146318
19990910    715835415
19990910    715835416
19990910    799844489
20123527    957714629
20123527    957714630
22000508    376790722
26981961    637378887
```

What could be the issue here

Thanks

Comment: If you provide us sample data, and expected result it will help to understand your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
SELECT t.Col1, t.Col2
FROM tblA t
inner join (
       SELECT Col1
         FROM tblA
        GROUP BY Col1
       HAVING ((Count(Col1))>1);
      ) tbl on tbl.col1=t.col1
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My requirement is to get the correspondence values of Col2 when ONLY Col1 is having duplicates. How it is possible?

Comment: Data added to the question

Comment: I've changed the answer, try it please.

Comment: This is working in MS Access with `INNER JOIN `. Can you explain the reason as to why the my initial query doesn't work

Comment: @ManthreePeiris try to run `SELECT Col1, Col2,count(1) FROM tblA GROUP BY Col1, Col2` you will see why.

Comment: @ManthreePeiris When you ran first query it gave results if there existed more than one group .  In the next query you grouped `two` columns together. So the results are going to be grouped by both of them . Say , if there were two columns of `first name ` and `last name` then according to second query it looks for duplicate entry for full name ( i.e first name and last name ) and not only first name .

Comment: @ManthreePeiris I'm glad I could help you. Don't forget you can also vote :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is no duplicate pairs in Col1 and Col2